# как в правилах firestore разрешить изменять отдельные поля и запретить остальные?

Tags: firebase, firestore

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть документ из коллекции `posts` в нем содержатся поля которые может изменять только пользователь создавший этот пост, но есть еще массивы которым нужны разрешения для добавления комментариев и лайков, как в правилах такое провернуть?

Я предпочел такую структуру так как в комментариях будут еще ответы, а сами комментарии будут отдельной коллекцией на уровне где находится коллекция `posts`, если создать коллекцию внутри `post` то к нему нужно еще коллекция ответы и так до бесконечности и это, как мне кажется, плохо влияет на оптимизацию.